# 14 Segment Display with turtle graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How can I convert input into 14 segment characters using turtle graphics?

I don't need a complete answer with code pasted in; I just need some ideas for how to go about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. Write a function that draws the complete ["union jack"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteen-segment_display) and make it accept up to 14 parameters (or a list thereof) saying which segments should be omitted. For each character, call this function with appropriate number of parameters.